# Minimum number of fractions to be summed up to $\frac45$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

What is the minimum number of fractions having numerator 1 and a natural number as denominator to be summed up to $\frac 45$?
I have tested with 2 fractions: $\frac1a + \frac1b = \frac45$ and get into the diophantine  equation: $5(a+b)=4ab$ and it seems this should have some solutions but can't find one!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering prime factorization gives that $5 \mid ab$ and, by relabeling if necessary, we can assume that $5 \mid a$, and in particular $\frac{1}{a} \leq \frac{1}{5}$. Substituting in the two-fraction equation gives $b \leq \frac{5}{3}$, so we must have $b = 1$, but this gives $\frac{1}{a} + 1 = \frac{4}{5}$, and the solution $a$ to this equation is negative, so there is no decomposition of $\frac{4}{5}$ as a sum of two such fractions.

On the other hand, if we permit ourselves three such fractions, we can see immediately that one of the fractions must be $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{3}$. (If not, each of the three fractions would be $\leq \frac{1}{4}$ and so would have sum $\leq 3 \cdot \frac{1}{4} < \frac{4}{5}$.) So, this reduces the problem to finding decompositions of either $\frac{3}{10}$ or $\frac{7}{15}$ into two such fractions. There turn out to be two solutions. (Incidentally, fractions of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, are often called **Egyptian fractions**.)

Comment: I have found three unit fractions summing up to $\frac45$:  $\frac12 , \frac15 , \frac{1}{10}$

Comment: Very good, can you find the other triple?

Answer (score 3):

For positive $a,b$, the equation $\frac45=\frac1a+\frac1b~$ has no solution, for if you allow $a,b$ are integer, $\frac45=\frac1a+\frac1b~$ has a unique solution that is $\frac45=\frac11+\frac1{-5}$.

**Proof for $a,b$  positive case, that $4/5=1/a+1/b$ has no solution:**

Let $0<a≤b$, then $4/5=1/a+1/b>1/a ~⟹ ~4/5>1/a ~⟹ a>5/4$, because $a$ is positive integer, so that $a≥2⟹1/a≤1/2~$, so that $1/b=4/5-1/a≥4/5-1/2=3/10⟹b≤10/3$, recalling that $0<a≤b$ and $a,b$ are postive integer. So only possible cases are $(a=2, b=2)$ or  $(a=2, b= 3)$ or  $(a=3, b= 3)$, and we can verify all these cases are not the solution. So $4/5$ can't be expanded into two postive unit fractions sum.

Then we can further test **if $4/5=1/a+1/b+1/c$ has a solution**, similar as above method in my proof. We only can find two positive solutions: $4/5=1/2+1/4+1/20=1/2+1/5+1/10$, so that the minimum number of unit fraction is 3, for presentation 4/5 as unit fractions sum.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $4/5 = 1/a + 1/b$ doesn't have any solutions where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.  To prove this, note that either $1/a$ or $1/b$ must be between $2/5$ and $4/5$, i. e. one of $a$ or $b$ must be between $5/4$ and $5/2$.  But the only integer in this range is 2, and if $a = 2$ then the corresponding $b$ isn't an integer.

So to express $4/5$ as a sum of unit fractions you need at least three fractions.  Can you find a way to do it with exactly three?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answers, here is another reason why 2 fractions is not enough. With some algebra, you can rearrange your Diophantine equation to:

$$a = \dfrac{5b}{4b -5}$$

Now, varying $b$, starting at $b = 1$ we get the following values for $a$, rounded to two decimals: $-5, 3.33, 2.14, 1.82, \dots$

After the last value, which is less than $2$, clearly we can never get an integer, because the function is monotonically decreasing as $b$ increases, but it is always greater than $\frac54$, which is itself greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b=4k$, $ab=5k$, where $k$ is a positive integer.

Then, $b=4k-a$, and substitute into $ab=5k$, we get:

$a(4k-a)=5k$

$a^2-4ka+5k=0$

Then let $ \Delta = 16k^2-20k=(4k)^2-20k=m^2$, where $m$ is another positive integer

And we have $\frac{(8k-5)^2-25}{4}=m^2$

Clearly $(8k-5)^2-25$ should be a perfect square number.

When $k=1$, $9-25<0$, impossible

When $k=2$, $121-25=96$ is not perfect square

When $k\ge3$, $(8k-5)^2-25>(8k-6)^2$.

So there's indeed no positive integer solution to $5(a+b)=4ab$.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some answers, indicating that it can't be done with two, so let's try with three.
The first fractions which comes in mind is $\frac{1}{2}$, which leaves us with:

$$\frac{4}{5} - \frac{1}{2}$$
$$ = \frac{8}{10} - \frac{5}{10}$$
$$ = \frac{3}{10}$$

It's easy to see that $\frac{3}{10} = \frac{2}{10} + \frac{1}{10} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10}$, hence:

$$\frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10}$$

..., resulting in this answer for the question:

3

:-)