# Solving Diophantine Equation $\frac{4}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ (A special case for Erdős–Straus conjecture)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found that when $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$, the Diophantine Equation $\frac{4}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ (1) has integer solutions. The strict proof is nearly ready.

It means at least when $4n+1$ is prime then the euqation (1) has no solution. It also means Erdős–Straus conjecture with $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$ always has solution, it can be used as an pre-decetor for under situation:

$\frac{4}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{4}{24n+1}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$.

Let $a=4t-1, b=t$, we can construct below table for $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$:
[image]

Comment: See Egyptian fractions. For $n=1$ it is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483130/minimum-number-of-fractions-to-be-summed-up-to-frac45?noredirect=1), and there are no solutions as you said.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks for commenting, Please note that: 1).  $n≠1$, because $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$, min. $n$ is 2, see above table I posted;2). If we talking about the Egypitan fractions(x,y postive integer) then 4/5 can't be expanded into two unit fractions. 3). But further more, if we didn't limit x,y are postive (extended math), 4/5=1/(-5)+1/1, also 4/13=1/3+1/(-39).

Comment: 1.) There is no reason to exclude $n=1$, see the answer below. 2.) Exactly. 3.) So what?

Comment: I mean, for the equation of your *title*, Solving Diophantine Equation $\frac{4}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$, there is no reason to exclude $n=1$. So your idea of $n=(4t-1)x-t$ is too narrow here. And indeed, the answer below also solves the case $n=1$.

Comment: How can you get n=1 from such I defined condtion $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$? Both $x,t$ are start from 1 (they are positive N). 3). It is extended question, similar case see negative numbers in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture

We normal do not study negative numbers, but they exactly exist there from modern math point of view.

Comment: Why exlude $n=1$, you can see below mathlove's proofs(I think it is good proof), not only for $n=1$, evey $4n+1$ if has $4m+1$ factor will has no solution, such as $4/25=1/x+1/y$, where $n=6$ has no solution. The condtions $n=(4t−1)x−t, x,t∈N+$ just revealed why $n=1$ to be exluded.

Comment: On the contrary, we can easily include $n=1$, because it belongs to the cases with no solutions.

Comment: Not only exlude n=1, it is too special case (narrow), becasue too many n have to be exluded, the $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$ just can do such exlude.

Comment: By the way, use such condtion $n=\left(4t-1\right)x-t,\ x,t\in N^+$, we can exlude 4n+1 primes and coposite number 4n+1 which can't express 4/(4n+1) into two unit fractions, such as 4/25, so it is a genral condtion.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying the both sides of
$$\frac{4}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$
by $4(4n+1)xy$ gives
$$16xy=4(4n+1)y+4(4n+1)x$$
which can be written as
$$(4x-4n-1)(4y-4n-1)=(4n+1)^2\tag1$$
Note here that $4x-4n-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$ and $4y-4n-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

- If every prime factor of $4n+1$ is of the form $4m+1$, then $(1)$ has no integer solution.
- If $4n+1$ has at least one prime factor of the form $4m+3$, then the integer solutions of $(1)$ are $$(4x-4n-1,4y-4n-1)=\bigg(k,\frac{(4n+1)^2}{k}\bigg),\bigg(\frac{(4n+1)^2}{k},k\bigg)$$
  i.e.
  $$(x,y)=\bigg(\frac{4n+1+k}{4},\frac{4n+1+\frac{(4n+1)^2}{k}}{4}\bigg),\bigg(\frac{4n+1+\frac{(4n+1)^2}{k}}{4},\frac{4n+1+k}{4}\bigg)$$
  where $k$ is a factor of $(4n+1)^2$ satisfying $k\equiv 3\pmod 4$.